# My wordpress page and post are not loading on webpage

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have changed my HTML template into WordPress by changing all HTML extensions into PHP and my all template parts are working properly. But my WordPress posts and pages are not loading on Web. Any idea why?

Comment: Need more information to be able to properly help. Have you looked into the WordPress loop? https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop. This is the main thing used to gather post / page content in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, you need to learn the template structure well. Here is the image for all you need https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png.

According to that, the post would be displayed by **single.php** and page would be display by **page.php**. And the fallback for both of them is **index.php** which mean if you don't have 1 or 2 of them, index.php will be used alternatively